# separating values ​between rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to separate values in "alpha" column like this

Start:

| alpha | beta | gamma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 |

End:

| alpha | beta | gamma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| X | X | X |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| X | X | X |
| C | 1 | 1 |

Thanks for help <3

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. Can you use code tags so things are in monospace?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```py
out = (df.groupby('alpha')
       .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame([['X', 'X', 'X']], columns=df.columns)]))
       .reset_index(drop=True)[:-1])
```

```
print(out)

  alpha beta gamma
0     A    1     0
1     A    1     1
2     X    X     X
3     B    1     0
4     B    1     1
5     B    1     0
6     X    X     X
7     C    1     1
```

Comment: Pretty good. +1

Comment: except this give an extra row in the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a range index as in the example, you can use:

```
# get indices in between 2 groups
idx = df['alpha'].ne(df['alpha'].shift(-1).ffill())

df2 = pd.concat([df, df[idx].assign(**{c: 'X' for c in df})]).sort_index(kind='stable')
```

Or without `groupby` and `sort_index`:

```
idx = df['alpha'].ne(df['alpha'].shift(-1).ffill())
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(idx+1)]
df2.loc[df2.index.duplicated()] = 'X'
```

output:

```
  alpha beta gamma
0     A    1     0
1     A    1     1
1     X    X     X
2     B    1     0
3     B    1     1
4     B    1     0
4     X    X     X
5     C    1     1
```

*NB. add `reset_index(drop=True)` to get a new index*

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'alpha':['X'],'beta':['X'],'gamma':['X']})
df = df.groupby('alpha',as_index=False).apply(lambda x:x.append(dfx)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   alpha  beta  gamma
0     A    1      0
1     A    1      1
2     X    X      X
3     B    1      0
4     B    1      1
5     B    1      0
6     X    X      X
7     C    1      1
8     X    X      X
```

To avoid adding a [X, X, X] at the end you can check the index first like:

```
df.groupby('alpha',as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x:x.append(dfx) 
    if x.index[-1] != df.index[-1] else x).reset_index(drop=True)
```